# jQuery ui sortable: Toggle enable - disable sortable on the lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, sortables

I have multiple lists generated via AJAX in my CMS admin page which enable a user to browse various levels of content. Each list element is generated on user click on previous list. I use jQuery:

```
$('#divid').on('click', 'ul', function() {
  //code to modify lists
  toggle_sortable();
});
```

[image]

Now I am trying to add a toggle button "Drag" to enable and disable jQuery-UI `sortable()`. However, since the lists are generated dynamically, I am unable to implement this flawlessly. Currently `toggle_sortable()` looks like:

```
function toggle_sortable() {
  $('#drag').on('click', function(){
    //statement to check if sortable() is enabled and change state accordingly
  });
}
```

Please help me find a solution in this situation. Basically I am unable to determine whether `sortable()` is enabled on a particular list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [**working DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/qpvz4qba/) **to initialize the list dynamically and Toggle sortable on the list on click of a button.**

To enable/disable sortable you can use the function as show below:

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
        //check if sortable() is enabled and change and change state accordingly
      // Getter
      var disabled = $("#sortable").sortable( "option", "disabled" );
      if (disabled) {
        $("#sortable").sortable( "enable" );
        $('#status').html('Sortable is now Enabled!!');
      }
      else {
        $("#sortable").sortable("disable");
        $('#status').html('Sortable is Disabled');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that I understood the question, but you keep piling click handlers to same elements. Either filter out those that have it, or each time you add, first remove, like so:

```

```
$('#drag').off("click", doit).on('click', doit);

function() doit{
//statement to check if sortable() is enabled and change state accordingly
// $(this) will be jquery reference to "#drag" element
}
```

```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your help! I am sorry I could not explain the problem precisely. However I used your input and ended up with the following code:

```
$('#drag').on('click', function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('sortable');
    if ($('#drag').hasClass('sortable')) {
        $('#div ul').sortable();
    } else {
        $('#div ul').sortable('destroy');
    }
});
```

The above code will enable and disable `sortable()` but it will not apply `sortable()` to newly appended elements. For those I used the following lines within the function that appends those lists.

```
if ($('#drag').hasClass('sortable')) {
    $('#ulid').sortable();
}
```